# iOS websocket receive NSStreamEventEndEncountered when sending data

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, websocket

I am building a server based on socket connection.

I've tried [JetFire websocket](https://github.com/acmacalister/jetfire) and [Socket Rocket websocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) for ios app.

Whenever data is sent via socket connection, a `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` event code always is returned.

`- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode;` is called with `eventCode` = `NSStreamEventEndEncountered`

I think there is no problem with my server, because it works well with web front end app.

Could anyone explain this for me?

Thanks in advance